# Amazon EC2 : Authentication Failure after error sudo: must be setuid root

Tags: sudo, amazon-ec2

I was trying to change permission on a folder in a Amazon EBS volume mounted on a Amazon EC2 running Ubuntu EC2.

When I entered the command

```
sudo chmod -R u+rw,go-rw /mnt/my-address
```

I go the message

> sudo: must be setuid root

Now I am unable to SSH into the my Amazon EC2 instance, getting the below message

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think your `sudo` program doesn't have proper permissions.

Change the permissions

`chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: Ok, but how do I access the instance. Unable to SSH only.

Comment: From which machine are you trying to run `sudo`?

Comment: I am SSHing to Amazon EC2 instance from my Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Not sure about this. @eric-hammond might help you. Please check with him.